# Two Sum Array - Brute Force - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    
    
    let index = 0
    let i = 1
    while (index <= nums.length - 1) {
            while (i <= nums.length - 1) {
                if (nums[index] + nums[i] === target) {
                    if (nums[index] === nums[i]) {
                        i = i + 1
                    }
                  return([index, i])
                } else {
                    i = i + 1
                }
            }
        index = index + 1
        i = 0
    }
};

twoSum([3, 3], 6)
```

expected output: [0, 1]
received: [0, 2]

description: Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

Comment: you might be better off with `for` loops rather than `while`

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 1):

@lucumt already pointed out that you should leave out two lines of your code. However, a slightly more conventional way of expressing your function would involve `for()` loops as they would make the code slightly more readable than the chosen `while()` construct. The inner loop should also always start at `index+1`, see below:

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  const res=[];
  for (let index=0; index <nums.length; index++) {
    for (let i=index+1;i <nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[index] + nums[i] === target ) res.push([index, i]);
    }
  }
  return res
}
console.log(twoSum([3, 3], 6)) // [[0,1]]
// second example:
console.log(twoSum([1,6,4,7,3,2,8,3], 6)) // [[2,5],[4,7]]
```

My snippet will return *all* possible sums in an array of arrays. If you only want the first solution, simply do `twoSum(arr,targetNum)[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove below code when you found the matched result

```
    if (nums[index] === nums[i]) {
        i = i + 1
    }
```

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    
    
    let index = 0
    let i = 1
    while (index <= nums.length - 1) {
            while (i <= nums.length - 1) {
                if (nums[index] + nums[i] === target) {
                  return([index, i])
                } else {
                    i = i + 1
                }
            }
        index = index + 1
        i = 0
    }
};

console.log(twoSum([3, 2, 0,1,4], 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this block.

```
                    if (nums[index] === nums[i]) {
                        i = i + 1
                    }
```

BTW, why you write this code from the start. You are not getting all the possible numbers. No matter how long the input array is, you just return 2 indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
let index = 0
while (index <= nums.length - 1) {
        let i = 0
        while (i++ <= nums.length - 1) {
            if (index!==i && nums[index] + nums[i] === target) {
              return([index, i])
            }
        }
    index++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for-loop with the same logic because it looks more simple.

```
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    for(let i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        for(let j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] === target){
                return [i, j]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  
  let index = 0
  let i = 1
  while (index <= nums.length - 1) {
          while (i <= nums.length - 1) {
              if (nums[index] + nums[i] === target) {
                  // if (nums[index] === nums[i]) {
                  //     i = i + 1
                  // }
                return([index, i])
              } else {
                  i = i + 1
              }
          }
      index = index + 1
      i = 0
  }
};

console.log(twoSum([3, 3], 6));
```

Skip that "if" statement above it will increase your i's value for this case.